# Matching records from several tables in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm a newbie in access. Hope you guys can enlighten me with my problems.

I have several tables which stored records according to the years. All the tables have the same set of fields. I am wondering if it is possible to search for a particular customer id, and produce me all his purchased records across the tables in my database. In a year, he may have several records while another year he may have none. If I use join function, it does not seem to be able to produce the results that I want.

examples:

Table 1 - 2001
the fields are as following:
Customer ID | Purchased Date | Purchased Time | Item Purchased |

Table 2 - 2002
Customer ID | Purchased Date | Purchased Time | Item Purchased |

Table 3 - 2003
Customer ID | Purchased Date | Purchased Time | Item Purchased |

Table 4 - 2004
Customer ID | Purchased Date | Purchased Time | Item Purchased |

I want the results to be as following (which means all compile under same column for the same type instead of creating new columns for the particular year):

Customer ID | Purchased Date 2001 | Purchased Time 2001 | Item Purchased 2001|

Customer ID | Purchased Date 2002 | Purchased Time 2002 | Item Purchased 2002|

Customer ID | Purchased Date 2003 | Purchased Time 2003 | Item Purchased 2003|

Customer ID | Purchased Date 2004 | Purchased Time 2004 | Item Purchased 2004|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to join the tables.  I believe what you want is a "union all" query.

Given this dataset...

```
Table 2001
CustId | Item
101      Widget A
101      Gizmo B
201      Widget A
201      Wedge C

Table 2002
CustId | Item
101      Widget A
201      Widget A
201      Wedge C
201      Wedge C

Table 2003
CustId | Item
101      Widget A
101      Gizmo B
101      Gizmo B
201      Gizmo B
```

The query would look like this...

```
SELECT item
FROM 'Table 2001'
WHERE CustId = 101

UNION ALL

SELECT item
FROM 'Table 2002'
WHERE CustId = 101

UNION ALL

SELECT item
FROM 'Table 2003'
WHERE CustId = 101
```

**Be sure to specify the same columns in the same order for each individual query so that the data will be matched up correctly in the query results.**

Answer (score 0):

You would be best off to create a new Table, leave out the year in column headers:

```
Customer ID | Purchased Date| Purchased Time | Item Purchased
```

You could merge your data via a query.